# Help identify brand of guitar

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

I recently got a guitar from my dad's friend for my birthday. He didn't play with it at all and gifted it to me. It's a really nice guitar, but I can't identify the brand of the guitar. The only clue I have about the guitar is the logo on the headstock, which I unfortunately can't decipher.

I would be very happy if someone could identify the brand!

[image: guitar headstock]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because identifying instruments isn't [on topic here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's a great idea, any time you get a new instrument, to take it to an expert to look over. They can probably best advise you about its history, authenticity, and whether it matters, as well as spot any work that's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the logo for Jaws Custom Guitars in Switzerland. Probably closed down at this point, as far as I can tell, they imported guitars from Asia, possibly china.

Comment: By answering, it encourages folk to ask questions which are not part of the site's remit.